# Changing width of body div in 2 column page with padding in menu. Getting gaps on the right

Tags: css, xhtml

I want my body div to fill the width of the page and sit on the right next to my side bar, I cannot understand how to get rid of the blank space created on the right. The problem seems to arise when I am using padding inside my side bar. My Code is below.

my html is

```
<div class="header">
</div>
<div class="side">
<a href="#"> menu</a> </br>
<a href="#"> menu</a> </br>
<a href="#"> menu</a> </br>
<a href="#"> menu</a> </br>
<a href="#"> menu</a>
</div>
<div class="body">
</div>
```

and my css is

```
.header{
background-color: #111;
width:100%;
height:120px
}

.side{
   float:left;
display:inline;
width:20%;
height:1000px;
background-color: #777;
padding:20px;

}

.body{
float:left;
display:inline;
height:1000px;
width:70%;
background-color: #d33;
}
```

​

Comment: What is happening that does not match what you expect?

Comment: You probably also want to use this, to clear any default margins and padding set by the browser:
-
`* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }`

Comment: A [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) always helps get your point across with this type of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're trying to support IE7 and earlier, you might try using display:table-cell instead. It kills off a lot of the BS we have to deal with in regard to floats.

Your html could be structured so:

```
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="side">
         <a href="#"> menu</a>
         <a href="#"> menu</a>
         <a href="#"> menu</a>
         <a href="#"> menu</a>
         <a href="#"> menu</a>
     </div>
     <div class="body"></div>
 </div>
```

And your CSS:

```
.header {
    background-color: #111;
    width:100%;
    height:120px;
}
.content { display:table; width:100%; }
.side, .body {
    display:table-cell;
    height:1000px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.side {
    width:20%;
    background-color: #777;
    padding:20px;
}
.side a {
    /* just as an aside, you REALLY don't need those <br/> tags... 
       just make your a tags inside your .side into block elements */
    display:block;
}
.body {
    width:80%;
    background-color: #d33;
}
```

See this jsFiddle for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/mori57/r8H4h/

Answer (score 2):

Forget about the `float:left;` of your `.body` and add `margin-left:20%;` instead of it. Then your `.body` class should fit the entire width of your page. Also you can work without `display:inline;` Here is my solution:

```
.side{
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: #777;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.body{
  margin-left: 20%;
  height:1000px;
  background-color: #d33;
}
```